# Denseness property

Tags: real-analysis

Let $t$ be large number on y-axis and $\gamma$ be the points in the rectangle $[0,1]\times[t,t+1)$ on coordinate plane such that the number of $\gamma$ in this rectangle is less than or equal to $c_1\log t$ for some positive constant $c_1$.

Why we can find $t_0\in[t,t+1)$ such that $\displaystyle\min_{\substack{\gamma}}|t_0-b|\geq \frac{c_2}{\log t_0}$ for some positive constant $c_2$, where $b$ is y coordinate of the point $\gamma$?

Comment: $\gamma$ is in a rectangle, so in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and you look for $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, so what does $|t_0-\gamma|$ mean ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I mean that the rectangle is on the coordinate plane and $\gamma$ is the point like $(1/2,t+1/2)$ (is in rectangle), so $|t_0-\gamma|$ is absolute value.

Comment: What is the absolute value between a $2-$coordinate point, and a real number ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Oh, I see!. If $\gamma$ is point $(1/2,t+1/2)$, then $|t_0−\gamma|=|t_0−(t+1/2)|$ (the distance from $t_0$ to y coordinate of the point $\gamma$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote by $\pi : (x,y) \mapsto y$ the projection on the second coordinate.

Take any $t_0$ such for all $\gamma$ in your rectangle, $\pi(\gamma) \neq t_0$ (this is possible because the $\gamma$ are in a finite number). For this $t_0$, again because the $\gamma$ are in a finite number,
$$\min_{\gamma}|t_0 - \pi(\gamma)| > 0$$

Now define
$$c_2 = \log(t_0) \times \min_{\gamma}|t_0 - \pi(\gamma)|$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I say that this is true because the points $\gamma$ are not too dense in the rectangle?

Comment: This is not the fact that the $\gamma$'s are not dense in the rectangle that makes it work, but the fact that the $\pi(\gamma)$ are not dense in $[t,t+1)$. Moreover, talking about density is here definitely not necessary, because the $\gamma$'s are in finite number... (the situation is much simpler)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.